# Not able to subset data

Tags: sas

I am trying to subset some data and the first call works fine.

```
IF tsalesYR12 >= 10000 THEN DELETE;
```

But when I reload the data and subset based on a different range it does not subset anything.

```
IF tsalesYR12 < 10000 and tsalesYR12 >= 250000 then DELETE;
```

Is there a problem with subsetting in the second example?  Or is there a more appropriate way to do this in `SAS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How could `tsalesYR12` be both less than 10,000 and greater than or equal to 250,000?

You mean `OR`.

```
IF tsalesYR12 < 10000 OR tsalesYR12 >= 250000 then DELETE;
```